# Geometrical interpretion of signed curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

What does signed curvature mean geometrically?
What is the difference between curvature and signed curvature? 
How i can determine signed curvature of curve from the graph of that curve?

Answer (score 4):

For (nice) space curves with a Frenet frame, by convention, curvature $\kappa$ is always positive. There are two ways in which "signed curvature" is used to refer to curves.

(1) For regular plane curves, we can decide that the unit tangent vector $T$ and principal normal vector $N$ will always make a *right-handed* basis. Then $T'(s)=\kappa(s)N(s)$, and $\kappa$ has a sign. If the curve stays convex, $\kappa>0$. (Assuming $T$ is heading in the positive $x$-direction, $\kappa>0$ means that the curve is bending upward.) If it switches from convex to concave, $\kappa$ becomes negative.

(2) For a normal slice of a surface, oriented with normal vector $\nu$, the signed curvature is positive when the principal normal $N$ and $\nu$ satisfy $N\cdot\nu>0$; i.e., the normal slice is bending toward $\nu$. And it is negative when $N\cdot\nu<0$, i.e., when the normal slice is bending away from $\nu$.